# 400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent. Sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

I've been having the title error from my browser when trying to set up SSL enabled nginx server with client verification on

Below is my nginx.conf:

```
keepalive_timeout  100;

server_tokens off;

server {
    listen 10.111.1.11:11111;
    server_name localhost;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key newca.key;
    ssl_client_certificate client.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_pass http://10.111.1.11::1234;
        proxy_ssl_name 10.111.1.11;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_certificate ca.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key newca.key;
    }
}
```

and below are my steps in generating the certificates and keys:

## Create the CA Key and Certificate for signing Client Certs

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
```

## Create the Client Key and CSR

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 4096
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
```

## My organization name,common name,email are different for ca.crt and client.crt values

## Common name for ca.crt is server IP

## Common name for client.crt is client IP

## Sign the client certificate with our CA cert

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt
```

## Convert to .p12 so import in OSX works

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey client.key -in client.crt -out client.p12 -name "MyKey"
```

## Removed passphrase for both ca and client keys

```
openssl rsa -in ca.key -out newca.key

openssl rsa -in client.key -out newclient.key
```

I tried uploading the client.crt and client.p12 to my browser as Trusted Root Certification Authorities and still to no avail (same error).

Any tips?

Comment: You are proxying to a http url. Take out all the `proxy_ssl_*` directives, you dont need them. And how are you providing the client certificate?

Comment: Hi. I tried your advice but still the same error. I generated the certs via the steps above and added it to my chrome browser by using the Manage certificate options and importing the file via the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Comment: In chrome you need to import it in `Your certificates` tab

Comment: That step is already done as mentioned above. If anything, it could be a chrome version difference as my chrome in the system is not up to date due to admin restriction.

Comment: Can you try from some other machine with latest chrome? Also what do you see in nginx logs?

Comment: logs say signal process started, no errors in error.log. Can't actually try other machine as this is a restricted environment.

Comment: In your `location /` add a `return 200 $ssl_client_verify;`, this will tell what was the SSL verification. Also change `ssl_verify_client optional;`, this way you will know what exact error you get

Comment: [https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_client_certificate] `ssl_client_certificate client.crt`  must target a Certificate Authority not a Certificate to let the browser choose which certificate is best suited

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606390/digital-ocean-node-js-nginx-and-cloudflare-400-badrequest-no-required-ssl-cer#comment107706146_55606390 was helpful for me.

Comment: Make sure the client certificate has been created with the 'SSL Client' purpose: see https://serverfault.com/questions/875229/two-way-ssl-error-400-the-ssl-certificate-error-just-for-client-certificate answer.