# Digital Ocean, Node.js, Nginx and Cloudflare (400 badrequest No required SSL certificate was sent)

Tags: node.js, nginx, certificate, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I am getting a 400 Bad Request error. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. On the phone it seems to work more often than not. I am not sure what the deal is but it is quite irritating.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name url url;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name url  url;

    ssl        on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;


    location / {
           proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to purge your cache on Cloudflare? https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-

Comment: Yup. It seems (not confirmed) that some ISP's DNS do not like to play nice with Cloudflare, It was one I never heard of, but when he changed his DNS to googles it worked perfectly for him.

Comment: Have you enabled SSL/TLS > Origin Server > Authenticated Origin Pulls?

Comment: @Majal Thank you SO MUCH! I wasted hours on this and could not figure out why my nginx config wasn't removing www and forcing https, and this was the one remaining problem. https://serverfault.com/a/258424/119666 was helpful beforehand.

Comment: @Ryan Happy to help. I'll post this as a possible answer then. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I also experienced this in one the new websites in my server that uses **CloudFlare.** The issue was that `SSL/TLS > Origin Server > Authenticated Origin Pulls` was not activated by default in the new website that shares server with my other sites which already had **Authenticated Origin Pulls** activated. So I just had to activate that for the new site. In other peoples' cases, that may be checked if there is a need to deactivate it.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I wasted hours on this and could not figure out why my nginx config wasn't removing www and forcing https, and this was the one remaining problem. https://serverfault.com/a/258424/119666 was helpful beforehand.